# IOS 11.3 Universal App Deployment Error: "Invalid Bundle. Your app supports Multitasking on iPad, so you must include the UILaunchStoryboardName"

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, deployment, app-store-connect

I have tried the following solutions with no success:

1. Check "Requires Full Screen" options for both iPhone and iPad
2. Check all device orientations for both iPhone and iPad
3. Uncheck all device orientations for both iPhone and iPad

My Universal app does support all device orientations and does not use storyboard. I am using Xcode version 9.3.

Comment: Solution 1 should disable iPad multitasking and fix the error. None of the other solutions have anything to do with the error.

Comment: How you are using splash screen? I think you need to use `UILaunchStoryboard` for showing splash.

Comment: Hi rmaddy, i tried solution 1 but it didn't fix error.

Comment: Hi Jayaswal, I am not familiar with this concept of splash screen, I believe I am not using it, my main screen is totally built and handled but my application. I have basically a main screen view controller that implements the slide out menu technical using a combo of left panel and central panel view controllers. I am not using story board in my app. I would like to avoid using story board at this stage.

Answer (score 1):

You have set your app to allow multitasking. If you specify that the app only works in full-screen mode you will not have this message. Add the following to your info.plist file:

```
<key>UIRequiresFullScreen</key>
<string>YES</string>
```

And you can submit your app.